# What are the practical advantages of keyboards with non-weighted keys vs. weighted hammer action?

Tags: piano, keyboard, recording, digital-piano, synthesizer

This is not a question about what type toy keyboard a beginning piano student should learn on if a real piano is not an option.  I am talking about professional quality keyboards in the above (to well above) $1000.00 U.S. range.

I have seen many professional keyboard players who prefer the non-weighted type keyboards over the weighted hammer acoustic piano type feel - even on their digital **pianos.**

I am wondering if there are practical advantages for the non weighted or semi-weighted velocity sensitive type keyboard (organ type feel) vs. the full weighted hammer style (real piano type feel).

I own both types, but seem to gravitate towards the weighted hammer action, perhaps because there was always an acoustic piano in my home growing up and I got used to playing that. But my Yamaha digital piano (with 88 weighted keys) does not have all the synth sounds that my other keyboard has.

But **is it just a matter of personal preference - or are there some things that are easier to do on a non-weighted hammer keyboard?**

I am considering the purchase of a keyboard that I can use for recording (in-home studio for my personal work) as well as on stage for live performance. In other words, both a work-station keyboard and a stage keyboard. More likely a synthesizer that can play piano sounds - but also all the other sounds I could use.  It seems that most **synthesizer's** have the **non-weighted** style keyboard feel.  **There must be a reason.**

If there are decided advantages for the non-weighted vs hammer action keys, I could certainly learn to like that type better.

**I am NOT asking for specific recommendations for which keyboard** to get. I am only trying to decide if I might be better served with a non weighted type keyboard (even though I would have to learn to like it).

Comment: I think I would find it very uncomfortable to use after-touch on a keyboard with weighted keys for any prolonged period. You need to be delicate if you are using it to say apply a vibrato effect and would not want a constant force of a weighted key trying to rebound during this.

Comment: @DaveEngineer I am not really familiar with "after touch".  Is this something I am likely to use live or more suited when using a keyboard as a midi controller to input into recording software?  Most of my keyboarding to date has been piano type stuff - but I have set up a home recording studio and would like to start using keyboard for that as well.

Comment: Once the key is fully depressed aftertouch is a secondary function where you can apply pressure to control the midi (do not confuse with velocity its something different). On a good keyboard this can assigned/routed to anything. LFO, volume, cutoff frequency, and other crazy stuff, etc. You need to see a video really

Comment: On a clavinet applying pressure can do a pitch bend. A synth can emulate that, of course.

Comment: Weighted action doesn't really affect aftertouch.  Weighted or not, the key still wants to come back up.

Comment: Note that 'non-weighted' and 'hammer' are mutually exclusive.  A keyboard that emulates a piano's hammer action will be weighted.

Comment: @LaurencePayne Good catch Laurence.  I edited the text of the question to reflect your accurate observation.  I wonder why nobody else caught that before now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What I've found is that the acoustic piano is the most expressive when played softly.  We all like loud, but anything can be loud and the ear will tune loud OUT after a while.  But it pays attention when things get quiet.  And that's where weighted keys really help - on a digital too.  If you don't have that weight, you'll get a more frequent oops-BANG during the quiet times.

But light/springy keys do have advantages.  More rapid attacks, glissandos are a lot easier.  And cheap/light are nice advantages if you can deal with the "hard(er) to play soft" part.

So if most of your music is loud, in a bar playin rock, light keys might be great.  If you're going deep into the expressive, you probably want weighted keys so your hands can relaaax and play sooo softly.

Answer (score 14):

- If you are playing an organ sound, you might want a keyboard that can feel and respond like an organ, rather than a piano
- It's possible to make a very shallow non-weighted action, which is helpful for some techniques (I like it better for triggering percussive sounds, for example)
- It's cheaper to make, so instruments are cheaper.
- The instrument is lighter to carry around.

Added note : Most synthesizers have a whole bunch of ways to affect the sound expressively beyond being velocity-sensitive - for many synth players, having a good set of controllers to route to expression / CC is more valuable than velocity sensitivity

Comment: What is CC the abbreviation for?

Comment: (MIDI) continuous controllers - MIDI messages you can send to a synth to change the sound while a it's playing.

Answer (score 6):

Hammer action is noisier.  Of course it is dwarfed by the sounds you hear, but when you have excellent reason for playing through headphones, that reason might also make light action desirable.

Also if your main instrument is not a grand piano but a harmonium or accordion or organ, there is no point in an percussive attack, and it may detract from the fine points of articulation on those instruments.

Answer (score 5):

I've played both types.  The non-weighted GOOD keyboards are significantly easier for a non-pianist to play.  The hammer-weighted actions are better if you want a touch-response (velocity) that emulates a real piano.  Some people say the non-weighted or non-hammer-action are toys; they aren't.  Some of them are very good (thinking of the Kawai K5000 keyboard here, which is semi-weighted, non-hammer, and super-fast and has aftertouch and velocity).

So the question: can you play some types of music better on a non-weighted keyboard?  I would say definitely YES.  Fast passages will be easier to play, trills will be quicker, and the keys will be more responsive.

Try out both.  See which one suits you.

Answer (score 5):

I think advantage of non-weighted keys is that for organ sounds you can do [smears/rakes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ia3Yb0duSSc)

Answer (score 3):

Weighted action is easier to play as a piano. Unweighted is a great deal lighter to carry to a gig!  (I think weighted is worth it!)

Answer (score 2):

These are the features of modern (21st century) digital keyboard / synthesizer / piano / organ:

- **Weighted** or not
- ***Graded* weighting** or uniform (graded implies heavier for lower notes to mimic the greater force necessary for *much* thicker bass strings in an acoustic grand piano.  Some digital pianos have even more key action features, such as the *double escapement* mechanism (see [this article](https://hub.yamaha.com/pianos/p-digital/a-quick-guide-to-weighted-keys/)).
- **Velocity sensitive** or not (attack speed controls MIDI velocity value which in turn controls the volume / color of the sound; a must have for any keyboard that has a piano sound)
- **After-touch sensitive** or not (additional pressure controls MIDI after-touch value, used in some synthesizers to control vibrato / volume within the note's duration, when controlling the sound of strings / woodwind)
- **Initial resistance** or not (this is to mimic the harpsichord plucking resistance, tracker pipe organ resistance to overcome the valve beneath the pipe to let the air in, or to simulate the electro-mechanical valve in more modern pipe organs, see [this article](https://www.parkeyorgans.com/key-and-windchest-actions/))

Every type has its advantages and disadvantages, **depending on what you're using the keyboard for**:

- Weighted keys in general (whether graded or uniform) can better control the *MIDI velocity range value* (0-127) so that your performance (especially piano sound) **can be more nuanced** especially now there is an abundance of piano VSTs that record real piano sounds in great detail (more than a dozen recordings per note).  I regularly set my digital piano to "Heavy" so I have more control over this.
- *Graded* weighting is useful for pianists who practice at home using a digital piano but **need to perform using regular acoustic grand piano in concerts**.  Otherwise, you'll be habituated to either play too loud on the upper range (which require *very* light touch in an acoustic grand piano) or play too soft on the lower range (those bass strings are at least 5x thicker).
- After-touch sensitive is a rare feature, but if you regularly do MIDI input with VST that responds to MIDI after-touch value, this feature would be indispensable for quicker input.  Also nice to have if you **use keyboard to simulate orchestral sounds** in live performance.
- Slight initial resistance feature is usually combined with light and uniform weighting.  This **helps organists who practice at home** to mimic the touch of real pipe organs, or **acoustic harpsichordists who need to control VST harpsichord sound**.
- Uniform, slightly (or non) weighted, and no initial resistance keybeds are useful for playing music that calls for **Hammond organ style playing** with occasional glissando, or to play non-classical piano sound (whether acoustic / electric sound).  This is similar to the light touch (although plasticky feel) of the classic Yamaha DX-7, Korg M1, or Roland D-50 synthesizers which at least has velocity sensitive action (some have after-touch too).

Answer (score 0):

Pianos are constructed to performed highly nuanced music where everything depends on the proficiency of a performer that can apply a whole range of touche.

Synthesisers are made to preform music that doesn't need nuances or any proficiency from the player – everything can be controlled by the envelopes of each synth or external controllers.

The advantages of a weighted keyboard is the ability to apply nuance to playing in the case where these nuances are 'readable' by the synth. Unless you need nuance you don't need a weighted keyboard.

Personally I'd choose a weighted keyboard any day – playing unweighted keyboards feels like playing a toy piano.

Comment: Can one be a church organist without having *any* proficiency, too?

Comment: Any proficiency in that specific skill – yes, you can not control dynamics or apply nuance on an organ through the keys. You can do that through external controllers, like on a synthesiser.

Answer (score 0):

Non-Weighted Keyboards are gentler on the fingers. I converted my Acoustic Piano to have a Non-Weighted Action by using a Tubular-Pneumatic Action that came out of an Aeolian Orchestrelle.

Answer (score -2):

I have studied piano for years, I can honestly say that digital pianos with weighted keys destroy my fingers and have caused me to be on prescription iprophen for 3 months the heal them which in turn, destroys the stomach. I own a 6 foot grand piano as well as a light weight key digital. Both cause me zero problems in my fingers. At the time I was taking lessons from a professional at a college, he was not able to detect any reason in my playing that would cause this trauma to my fingers. So I sold the weighted digital haven't had a problem since (over four years) until last week I played a digital weighted key piano, and in nearly 20 minutes of playing, I felt the EXACT SAME PAIN. Be careful and let your body tell you which you like.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense.  The keys are completely passive, so if you're experience pain it's something to do with your technique.  Piano teachers are not necessarily well-versed in kinesiology.

Comment: Your last sentence has value, but I would be careful when making broad statements like this. I use a digital piano with weighted keys, and experience no such problems. As usual, with ergonomic issues, don't "push through the pain." Because that's just dumb. Trying to diagnose the problem is the right thing to do, but, to agree with Matthew, I can't think of a possible reason that weighted keys would cause pain like that.

Comment: It is indeed a strange one. I play both, most days, and luckily have never experienced what Tony has.

Comment: One possibility is that the particular weighted key digital pianos you played were somehow different in other ways than your 6 foot grand.  Perhaps they were tilted on the stand at a different angle or perhaps the keyboard stand placed the keys at a different height causing you to alter your angle of attack.  Just speculation on my part.